# Trying to read my .json data in python but keep getting an error

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I have a simple code to be able to read my json data in python and convert to dictionary so I can use it for sqlite. However, I keep running into this error.

Code I ran:

```
import json

with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    json_str = f.read()
    json_value = json.loads(json_str)
    print(type(json_value))
```

I have a set of data like this:

```
{"_id":{"$od":"5f12"},"ready":true,"createdon":{"$date":1609687444800},"lastLogin":{"$date":1858},"position":"consumer","signUp":"Email","state":"WI"}
{"_id":{"$od":"5f12"},"ready":true,"createdon":{"$date":1609687444800},"lastLogin":{"$date":1858},"position":"consumer","signUp":"Email","state":"WI"}
```

The error I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_to_sqlite.py", line 5, in <module>
    json_value = json.loads(json_str)
  File "/Users/malaba/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/malaba/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 186)
```

Comment: You need a comma between the dictionaries, then you need a single root element, which can be a list. so I’d wrap the final result with a []

Comment: You can't put multiple JSON strings to a file. If you want to put multiple objects in the JSON file, you should write them as an array.

Comment: @rv.kvetch I didn't quite understand what you mean. I know I should but I'm starting out and still figuring it out. I would really appreciate it if you could elaborate more on your comment above. Thank you!

Comment: Well, am typing on my phone so it kinda hard, but as @barmer said above, you need an array as the root element here, so like [{…}, {…}] for example - note here each element is a dictionary. I think you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

@rv.kvetch is right, the problem is that your `users.json` file has **two distinct json strings**, i.e. you have two dictionaries stored in your file when you can have at most one. An easy way to fix this is to wrap the dictionaries in a list (hence, you have one json object that holds all your other objects). The newly formatted `users.json` file would look something like this:

```py
[{"_id":{"$od":"5f12"},"ready":true,"createdon":{"$date":1609687444800},"lastLogin":{"$date":1858},"position":"consumer","signUp":"Email","state":"WI"},
{"_id":{"$od":"5f12"},"ready":true,"createdon":{"$date":1609687444800},"lastLogin":{"$date":1858},"position":"consumer","signUp":"Email","state":"WI"}]
```

Please make note of the opening and closing braces and the extra comma separating the dictionaries in your new file. Reading the json file would be the same procedure as before, but if you wanted to pull a specific dictionary out of your returned json, you would need to index the list accordingly. More details on the `json` module can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

EDIT:

If you have a large data file, this sort of operation is not feasible to do manually so you will have to get clever to look for additional structure to the file. For example, if you know that each dictionary in the file is separated by a newline and there are **no other newline characters in your file** (similar to the example you provided), then you can automatically do this conversion like so:

```py
import json

with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    new = [json.loads(x) for x in f.read().splitlines()]

with open("users.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(new, f)
```

Comment: What is the best way to converting the dictionaries to a list or array?

Comment: @malaba just to be clear, you don't want to *convert* the dictionaries into arrays, you want to **wrap** them in an array. You can do that by creating an empty list and appending each dictionary to it manually. In my solution, I simply put both dictionaries in your file into a list (note the addition of opening and closing braces as well as a comma between the dictionaries).

Comment: I have a large data file, is there anyway of doing it other than manually?

Comment: @malaba I edited my answer to give you some insight on what you can do about that, I hope it was helpful.